# Field of view in unity changes with oculus

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

There seems to be a problem with the field of view within Unity and the Oculus rift. The moment u play the game mode, the field of view changes to another number. If you turn off 'virtual reality supported' it fixes it. Although no use if you want to use the Oculus! any solutions to being able to change the field of view to what you want it to be?

Comment: That's not a problem, that's the way the Oculus works. The Oculus Rift needs to be around 90 degrees for immersion. Any greater like 150 degrees, the goggles would have to be big and curved.

Comment: it seems to change the field of view to 106.188 regardless what I want it to be. Even if I changed it to 106.288 it still changes back. Is there no room to change it?

Comment: This is because that's what the Oculus Rift is using. The hardware is configured to that. Have you tried using `Camera.fieldOfView`?

Comment: I have personally tried camera.fieldofview.  It brings up a message that suggests that it is not allowed.

Comment: Interesting. @matt_turner_2017 looks like you may have to make do for now.